# How to display a Context Menu in kendo Treeview

Tags: treeview, contextmenu, kendo-ui-angular2

There is a way to display a context menu with right click on a `TreeView` item node?

Comment: What did you do so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see a [how to article](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/treeview/how-to/integration/show-context-menu) about a similar scenario.